# How to add a Glyphicon to the place holder in a search bar, HTML, Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[This is a screen shot from my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URjU9.png)

I want to add a search Glyphicon to that search bar how do I using  bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add bootstrap.icons.css file to html page

> cdn address : https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css
>
> document : https://icons.getbootstrap.com/

using this code :

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter A Product ...">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my main.css, i had -

```
<form id="search" method="get" class="d-flex" action="#">
                    <input id="input" class="form-control me-2" type="text" placeholder="Search products" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning text-light" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
                    </form>
```

and then to add an icon inside it, in my styles.css, i did,

```
#input{
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    display: block;
    padding: 9px 4px 9px 40px;
    background: transparent url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' class='bi bi-search' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E") no-repeat 13px center;

}
```